# R remove characters surrounding wildcard in string

Tags: html, r, replace, gsub

I have a vector listing the various types of HTML found in a website that contain URLs, which is characterized by the wildcard: **([^<]*)**. So far, I've been able to pull the links into a dataframe I need but am having trouble cleaning them up so they can be accessed.

How do I remove all the tags without affecting the URL?

```
# Vector of HTML tags surrounding URL
x <- c('\t\t\t<div><a href=\"([^<]*)\">([^<]*)</a></div>','\t\t</tr><tr><td><a href=\"([^<]*)\">([^<]*)</a></td>','\t\t\t<td><a href=\"([^<]*)\">([^<]*)</a></td>')
```

Input:

```
URL <- "https://www.atf.gov/resource-center/data-statistics"
html <- paste(readLines(URL))
```

Output:

| Link | Title |
| --- | --- |
| "https://www.atf.gov/file/144871/download" | Canada 2014-2019 |
| "https://www.atf.gov/node/79436" | 2019 |

Code I'm currently working with:

```
dlall <- list()
for(i in x){
  datalines <- grep(i,html,value=TRUE)
  dl_all <- rbind(data.frame(datalines), data.frame(dl_all))
  }
```

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: Just added to the OP

Comment: And what do you need to get? A list of URLs? If yes, from anywhere or from `<a href="....">` tags?

Comment: Yes, I decided to add both the expected output and the code I currently am working on. I'm hoping to grab the url within the web page and it's title in a separate column.

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/9YHFkb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) using R >= 4.1:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.atf.gov/resource-center/data-statistics"
df <- read_html(url) |> html_nodes("a") |> 
  {\(x) data.frame(
    Link = x |> html_attr("href"),
    Title = x |> html_text())
  }()
```

Giving:

```
tail(df)
                                                        Link                              Title
203    https://www.justice.gov/jmd/eeo-program-status-report                        No Fear Act
204 https://oig.justice.gov/hotline/whistleblower-protection Whistleblower Rights & Protections
205                        https://www.atf.gov/home/site-map                           Site Map
206 https://www.atf.gov/resource-center/accessibility-policy           Accessibility & Plug-Ins
207                              https://www.atf.gov/<front>                            ATF.gov
208                                  https://www.justice.gov         U.S. Department of Justice
```

Comment: `\(x)` is the same as `function(x)` as of R 4.1, it's just shorthand.